# Find the average value in MongoDB from JSON

Tags: json, mongodb, apache-spark

In my MongoDB (export from JSON file) I have database "dab" with structure like this:

```
id:"1"
datetime:"2020-05-08 5:09:56"
name:"namea"
lat:55.826738
lon:45.0423412
analysis:"[{"0":0.36965591924860347},{"5":0.10391287134268598},{"10":0.086884394..."
```

I'm using that db for spark analysis via MongoDB-Spark Connector.

My problem is field "analysis" - I need average result for all values from every interval ("0", "5", "10", ..., "1000"), so I have to sum 0.36965591924860347 + 0.10391287134268598 + 0.086884394 + ... and divide by number of intervals (I have 200 intervals in every column), and finally multiply the result by 100.

Answer (score 1):

My solution would be this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      analysis: {
        $map: {
          input: "$analysis",
          in: { $objectToArray: "$$this" }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      analysis: {
        $map: {
          input: "$analysis",
          in: { $first: "$$this.v" }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $set: { average: { $multiply: [ { $avg: "$analysis" }, 100 ] } } }
])
```

[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qyMGliwrHaH)

Comment: How can I add this like a new column in MongoDB Compass, if it is possible?

Comment: Yes, I have columns id, datetime, name, lat, lon and analysis, and I would like to add new column "average" with your above solution.

Comment: Simply `db.collection.updateMany({}, [ the pipeline stage I provided ])`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I guess there is no other way to do this? 
Because I have mongodb version 3.6.8 and it doesn't support insert as array, only as object.

Comment: No, it was added in 4.2. Then you need to run a loop: `db.collection.aggregate([...]).forEach(function(doc) {db.updateOne({_id: doc._id}, {$set: {average: doc.average}} )})`

Comment: sorry, I am beginner for this and I don't know how to apply it on my example, because there are a differences in aggregate (for example- old version doesn't support $first etc.). Can you, please, add solution for version 3.6.8. in your answer above?

Comment: Replace `{$first: "$$this.v"}` by `{ $arrayElemAt: [ "$$this.v", 0 ] }`

Comment: One more question, I promise. I have an error "input to $map must be an array not string" - the problem is in 6th line. Is there any alternative for it?

Comment: Then maybe an some document `analysis` is single value rather than an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$reduce` on that array,sum the values,and then divide with the number of elements and then multiply with 100

```json
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "average": {
        "$multiply": [
          {
            "$divide": [
              {
                "$reduce": {
                  "input": "$analysis",
                  "initialValue": 0,
                  "in": {
                    "$let": {
                      "vars": {
                        "sum": "$$value",
                        "data": "$$this"
                      },
                      "in": {
                        "$add": [
                          "$$sum",
                          {
                            "$arrayElemAt": [
                              {
                                "$arrayElemAt": [
                                  {
                                    "$map": {
                                      "input": {
                                        "$objectToArray": "$$data"
                                      },
                                      "as": "m",
                                      "in": [
                                        "$$m.k",
                                        "$$m.v"
                                      ]
                                    }
                                  },
                                  0
                                ]
                              },
                              1
                            ]
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "$size": "$analysis"
              }
            ]
          },
          100
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[You can test the code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tWbsWarrcaU)

But this code has 1 problem, you save data in documents, and MongoDB
doesn't have a function like `get(document,$$k)`, the new MongoDB v5.0 has a `$getField` but still accepts only constants no variables.
I mean we cant do in your case `getField(doc,"5")`.

So we have the cost of converting each document to an array.